# AngularJS getting JSON data from array2 in array1

Tags: angularjs, dropdown

I have JSON like this

```
{
    "cars":[
        {
            "id":"012",
            "model":"honda",
            "parts":[
                {
                    "id":"p1",
                    "name":"tyre",
                },
                {
                    "id":"p2",
                    "name":"muffler",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"022",
            "model":"vw",
            "parts":[

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am new to AngularJS and I have 2 dropdowns, DROPDOWN1 showing car models like:

```
DROPDOWN1
honda
vw
```

and DROPDOWN2 that is supposed to be loaded with parts for selected car model in DROPDOWN1.  For example, if I select "honda" in DROPDOWN1, DROPDOWN2 should be loaded with:

```
DROPDOWN2
tyre
muffler
```

If I select "vw" in DROPDOWN1, then DROPDOWN2 will not load since there are no parts for VW.

I have html with 2 select (dropdowns) like this, note that I am using **ng-options** rather than **repeat**:

```
<p><strong>Select a car</strong></p>
<select 
    required
    ng-change="selectCarAction()"
    ng-model="selectCar" 
    ng-options="car.model for car in cars track by car.id">
  <option value="" label="Select a car"></option>  
</select>

<p><strong>Select a part</strong></p>
<select 
    required
    ng-model="selectPart" 
    ng-options="part.name for part in parts track by part.id">
  <option value="" label="Select a part"></option>  
</select>
```

And in my js file, I get my car response data like:

```
      $scope.myData= JSON.stringify(myresponse.data);
      $scope.cars= myData.data.cars;
```

, then I have function to get selected car and the intention is to also load DROPDOWN2 once I get selected car:

```
$scope.selectCarAction = function(){
  if ($scope.selectCar == null){
    console.log("You selected car: N/A");
  } else {
    console.log("You selected car: " + $scope.selectCar.model);
    $scope.parts= $scope.selectCar.parts;    
  }
};
```

While my DROPDOWN1 loads fine, my DROPDOWN2 is never loaded but in the js function above, my $scope.parts gets the parts.  How do I load these into my DROPDOWN2?

Comment: you don't stringify data to use it. Look at error thrown in console by  next line when you do that

Comment: I am, look above for $scope.myData.  Thanks

Comment: spelling? "partin" instead of "part in" in your ng-options ???

Comment: actiually, that is not the issue, it was my mis typing but you were very close.  I used "partin car.part" instead of "part in parts".  That fixed it.  I updated the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the original post.  I was using "part in car.part" instead of "part in parts" in my ng-option above.  That fixed the issue.